# How to fix/correctly initialise/clean up matrix class leaking memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The following example code using the SmallMatrix-class from [SG2 package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sg2/) seems to cause a memory leak. In this simplified example only little memory is leaked. But my more involved algorithm tends to run out of memory.

```
#include "small_matrix.hpp"
int main() {
    SmallMatrix<double> S(1);
}
```

See the Valgrind output below.

```
8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
   at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x400D4A: SmallMatrix<double>::SmallMatrix(int) (small_matrix.hpp:1347)
   by 0x400C15: main (test.cpp:3)
```

The relevant constructor is the referenced section of the source code:

```
template <class T>
SmallMatrix<T>::SmallMatrix(int the_m)
: small_matrix<T> (the_m, new T [the_m])
{
    T * alloced_entries;
    try
    {
        alloced_entries = new T [the_m];
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc)
    {
        throw SMALL_MAT_NO_MEMORY;
    };
    small_matrix<T>::init (the_m, 1, alloced_entries);
}
```

[Find a listing of small_matrix.hpp here.](http://sourceforge.net/p/sg2/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/DataStructures/small_matrix.hpp)

Line 1347 reads:

```
: small_matrix<T> (the_m, new T [the_m])
```

The destructor can be found at line 822:

```
~SmallMatrix () {delete [] SmallMatrix<T>::entry;};
```

This seems fine to me. Is it? Is memory really leaked? How to fix it? Am I maybe declaring or initialising incorrectly?

Comment: Fix your matrix class to use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` and your problems will probably go away.  Also, where is your assignment operator and copy constructor (since you are using pointers)?

Comment: Is your constructor calling `new` twice -- once the initialization list and once in the body of the constructor?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I'm trying my best to use this class, but I didn't write it and I'm not an experienced c++ programmer.

Comment: Well, you were given a buggy class.   There are other things wrong with it besides the memory leak.  Self assignment of a matrix object, is not checked for -- that's another issue.  In other words `SmallMatrix A;  A = A;` will cause memory related errors.  Another is the usage of `memcpy` during the copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are both using the initialization list and an explicit initialization.

The constructor of small_matrix calls init() with the array you created in the initialization list. Then you manually call init() that replaces the pointer to the array. So you loose the reference to the array created in the initialization list.

```
template <class T>
SmallMatrix<T>::SmallMatrix(int the_m)
: small_matrix<T> (the_m, NULL)
{
    T * alloced_entries;
    try
    {
       alloced_entries = new T [the_m];
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc)
    {
        throw SMALL_MAT_NO_MEMORY;
    };
    small_matrix<T>::init (the_m, 1, alloced_entries);
}
```

Should fix the memory leak